# Change Drupal Gmap marker z-index

Tags: google-maps, drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal ExtendedGmap View. View results show as markers on the map. Marker type is determined by a custom field (NOT a field on the content type, but rather a PHP field calculated from the View) so the first view result marker is set to 'orange' and all other row markers are set to 'green'. The problem I have is that I want my first (orange) marker to show above the others. I have found a way to change the first marker z-index value in THEME_preprocess_gmap_views_view_gmapextended function:

```
$vars['markers'][0]['opts']['zindex'] = '9999';
```

But this is not reflected on the map and the first marker is still buried (in fact the first marker ends up somewhere in the middle of the stack).

How do I get my first View row marker on top?

I tried the Javascript mentioned on [this page](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/change-google-maps-marker-z-index-values-by-given-weight-when-using-gmap-module/2011-10-27) but don't really understand it and it doesn't work for me.

```
Drupal.gmap.addHandler('gmap',
  function (elem)
  {
    var obj = this;
    obj.bind('preparemarker',
      function (marker)
      {
        marker.opts.zIndexProcess =
        function (marker,b)
        {
          return this.zindex ? this.zindex : -99999;
        };
      }
    );
});
```

I am using Drupal 7 and Gmap 7.x-2.9

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. Googlemaps API V3 uses zIndex (capital 'I') instead of zindex. Changed that and works as expected - markers stack correctly.

Example code:

```
$vars['markers'][0]['opts']['zIndex'] = '9999';
```